# Does user specified methods in JpaRepository gets executed in single transaction?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I have custom methods in `JpaRepository` and they are called recursively. `firstMethod` is actually calling data from DB. `secondMethod` and `thirdMethod` are calling `firstMethod` and `secondMethod` respectively.

Does thirdMethod executes in a single transaction? i.e., I want entire query list to be fired in a single go, fetch entire list from db and return in a single go instead of multiple queries fired per object in list.

```
public interface SomeDao extends JpaRepository<SomeObject, SomeObjectId> {

    @Deprecated
    @Query("custom query")
    Slice<SomeObject> firstMethod(BigInteger a, Timestamp b, Pageable c);

    default Optional<SomeOtherObject> secondMethod(SomeObject someObject) {
        // calls first method
        // object has separate fields that apply in first method -> someObject.a, someObject.b etc
    }

    // I want to know whether third method gets executed in single transaction???
    default List<Optional<SomeOtherObject>> thirdMethod(List<SomeObject> listOfObjects) {
        // calls second method for a list of objects
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are confusing transactions and query execution.

If everything runs in a single transaction depends on the `@Transactional` annotation you put or don't put on your repository method.

What query gets executed solely depends on `firstMethod` and it's query annotation. It will get executed for each invocation of the method.